# count the occurrences of a string in a log file per hour (with a shell script)

Tags: shell

I want to make a script to count the occurrences of a specific string (domain name)
from a log file (mail log) per hour, in order to check how many emails they sent per hour.

I know there are many easy and different ways to find a script into a file (like grep etc)
and count the lines (like wc -l) 
but I don't know how to do it per hour.

Yes I can call the script every 60 minutes via a cron job but this would read the log file from the beginning till the moment the script was executed..and not the lines made in the last 60 minutes, and I don't know how to overcome this.

Note:

the command that I'm using the show all the sent emails per domain is :

```
\# cat /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog | grep -i qmail-remote-handlers \
| grep from | awk {' print $6 '} | gawk -F@ '{ print $2 }' \
| sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
```

the result is like this:

```
      8 domain1.tld
     45 domain34.tld
    366 domain80948.tld
etc etc
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long. You'll need to show some lines of the log file format, so that the time information is visible. The basic technique will be to create a pattern that matches all the times in the relevant hour, but the details will depend on date format in the log file.  Also, are you seeking the analysis over a single hour, over all the time that's recorded in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

The main point of the question is this one:

```
Yes I can call the script every 60 minutes via a cron job but this would read the log file
from the beginning till the moment the script was executed..and not the lines made in the
last 60 minutes, and I don't know how to overcome this.
```

How could you solve the problem?

1. You could save the number of lines in the log file lat time you processed it. After that skip these lines using `sed`.
2. The same as in 1 but save the number of bytes in processed file; then skip it using `dd`.
3. You could rotate (rename) the file after processing it (this method has disadvantage that you need to reconfigure your system to make log processing)

I personally would chose method 2. It is very efficient and very simple to implement.